# Is there a way to make drawer visible again?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v6

When I click the menu icon on the right side on the header. Drawer does not open however I am able to click some of the drawer items though and it navigates to them. I have not made any changes to my code and this has been working normally before.

Here is my navigation file https://gist.github.com/Jukez17/612856725ff2473b392283b248c2d2c7

On the iOS when I click the menu icon it just gives blank white screen.

There is no crash indications or logs for this.

I have tried to downgrade "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.2" and "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.10.2", to older versions but that hasn't helped either.

I am expecting my drawer to open and to see my drawer items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [navigation.getParent().openDrawer() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399942/navigation-getparent-opendrawer-not-working)